# Android pay card registration, token generation, and verification

Tags: android, credit-card, payment

I was trying to find information about Android Pay and how it handles card information when adding it to Android Pay and how are token information verified. I was not able to find detailed information.

When adding a new card to Android Pay you have to provide information like PAN, expiration date and CVC (or similar). What then happens in the background?

Does then Android Pay send this information to the cloud? What is in this case "the cloud"? Google servers?

The token for the credit card should be generated in this cloud and then transported back to Android and stored.

How is then token information verified when received by merchant or payment processor? Do they send token to "cloud" and receive back the true card information which can be send to acquirer? Or how is the verification processes integrated with Android Pay?

Is there any difference for loyalty card and standard payment card in Android Pay flows?